# SQL Server create a task with xp_cmdshell and set if the task failed restart every time

Tags: sql-server, scheduler, windows-task-scheduler

I know how to create a task in SQL Server 2008 by query, but I can not configure this "if the task fails, restart every time" and how to disable "stop the task if it runs longer than" .

This it is my code

```
declare @cmd varchar(max), @Path varchar(max), @FileToExecute varchar(max)

set @Path = 'C:\MyAppFolder'
set @FileToExecute = 'MyApp.exe'

set @cmd = 'schtasks /create /tn "DataTask" /tr "'''+@Path+'\'+@FileToExecute +'''" /sc onstart /RU Administrator /RP password /F /delay 0015:00'  

exec xp_cmdshell @cmd  , NO_OUTPUT

set @cmd = 'schtasks /run /TN "DataTask"'            
exec xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPIJY.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think can do it all from command line.. this is all you can do

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx

but... you could have made an XML file by exporting and existing job:

```
schtasks /create /xml "MyExportFile.xml" /tn "Name of the New Task"
```

and adjust the settings like this:

```
<Settings>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RestartOnFailure>
      <Interval>PT30M</Interval>
      <Count>5</Count>
    </RestartOnFailure>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
</Settings>
```

And you can them use that as a template for importing from command line

Comment: I just make the changes on my task and after that i exported to a xml file to create a new task from the xml with the changes include.

Thanks

Comment: This works for my  

schtasks /create /tn "Name of the New Task"  /xml "MyExportFile.xml" /tn /RU Administrator /RP password

Answer (score 0):

I just make the changes on my task and after that i exported to a xml file, to create a new task from the xml with the changes include.

This worked for my

```
declare @cmd varchar(max), @Path varchar(max), @FileToExecute varchar(max), @XmlFile varchar(100)

set @Path = 'C:\MyAppFolder'
set @FileToExecute = 'MyApp.exe'
set @XmlFile = 'MyApp.xml'

set @cmd = 'schtasks /create /tn "DataTask" /tr "'+@Path+'\'+@XmlFile+'"  /RU Administrator /RP password'  

exec xp_cmdshell @cmd  , NO_OUTPUT

set @cmd = 'schtasks /run /TN "DataTask"'            
exec xp_cmdshell @cmd
```